# Is ARM big.LITTLE is numa system?

Tags: arm, numa

I have hardkernel ODROID XU3 board.
It is Exynos 5422 and, it is big.LITTLE system.

And, ARM big.LITTLE is NUMA system or not?

I already know that big.LITTLE has each cache.

Comment: NUMA is only really relevant if you have multiple memory nodes; when all the memory's in just one place it's essentially uniform by definition. CPU topology is another matter.

Comment: Thanks you. So... "big core" and "little core" there can be located on different nodes?

Comment: They _could_ be, if someone ever built such a thing, but you're essentially just conflating several unrelated concepts; a multiprocessor system can have different levels of cache shared between different sets of CPUs (that's been the norm for decades); a multiprocessor system can have some CPUs which are microarchitecturally heterogeneous, yet ostensibly compatible; a multiprocessor system can have multiple memory controllers, each of which certain sets of CPUs may have faster access to than others. None of those things are directly related to each other.

Comment: Thx a lot. This was very helpful.